# Showing that a proposition is not a tautology using logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**What I've researched**:

I have seen a lot of questions where you have to show that something is a tautology using logical equivalence where the result if True is obvious enough to be right but what exactly merits that something is not a tautology. I have not seen any questions where the proposition was not a tautology and it was proved so using only logical equivalence. I can do the job by using a truth table but the question stresses that it is not an option.

**My question**

To prove that something is not a tautology is it enough if you have a proposition that cannot be broken down further or do you require it to must give a false.

The question I must solve is to show that $a \vee \lnot((\lnot a \vee b) \rightarrow \lnot a) $ is a tautology using logical equivalences.

I have solved it as follows:

$$
a \vee \lnot (\lnot(\lnot a \vee b) \vee \lnot a) \tag{Removing implication}
$$

$$a \vee ( \lnot \lnot ( \lnot a \vee b) \land \lnot \lnot a)  \tag{De Morgan's, double -}$$
$$
a \ \vee \ (  a \ \land ( \lnot a \vee b)) \tag{Commutative}\\ 
$$
$$
a \ \vee ( (a \land \lnot a) \vee (a \land b) )\tag{Distributive}\\
$$
$$
a \ \vee ( F  \vee a \land b) \tag{Negation}\\
$$
$$
a \ \vee  a \vee\ b \tag{Identity}
$$

Now I don't know if I can break it down any further from here and I know via truth tables that this proposition is not a tautology, but is this enough to show that it is not or does it need to go all the way down to a False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $a \ \vee \ (  a \ \land ( \lnot a \vee b)) \tag{Commutative}\\$ you can also do $(a \ \lor \   a )\ \land (a\lor (\lnot a \vee b)) \tag{Distributive}\\$ $a \ \land \ (  a \ \lor  \lnot a \vee b) \tag{Associative and Equivalence}\\$ $a \ \ \tag{Equivalence }\\$ with the last equivalence holding because $a\lor\lnot a$ is a tautology.

Then your statement is equivalent to $a$, so its truth value is the same as the truth value of $a$. If $a$ is a logic variable, then your statement can be false if $a$ is false, so it is not a tautology. If $a$ is another statement, then your statement is a tautology if and only if $a$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last step is wrong. If you think about the third line, if $a$ is true, then the entire thing is true because of the 'or'. If $a$ is not true, then both terms are not true because both terms are dependent on the truth of $a$.

You should end up with this reducing to $a$. Hence the statement is dependent on the truth of its statement. A tautology, as I remember it, is if the statement is true regardless of the truth of the statements involved. Hence $P$ or not $P$ is a tautology because it is true without knowing the truth of $P$. However in this case, the statement is dependent on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you will need a technique other than logical equivalence leading to False.

If a formula is a tautology, then its valuations on all possible models of the variables all result in True. If you can show a formula is logically equivalent to False, then its valuations on all possible models of the variables all result in False.

For the formula $a \lor a \lor b$, it's easy to see that some models ($a$ and $b$ both False) result in the formula being False, and some models ($a$ and $b$ both True) result in the formula being True. So it's not always True and not always False.

The simple way of showing it's not a tautology is to provide just one model for the variables for which the formula's result is False. Or if you absolutely need to avoid that, you could maybe rely on some other observations, like:

> A formula in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) is a tautology if and only if each disjunction within it contains both $v$ and $\lnot v$ for some variable $v$.

Here $a \lor a \lor b$ is in CNF with one disjunction, but it does not contain any $\lnot v$ literal at all.